# Spring: Accessing field from final method returning null

Tags: java, spring

So I came across a very weird bug in my project. I had the following two classes

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public abstract class World {
    String name;

    public World(String name) {
          this.name = name;
    }

    final void print() {
          System.out.println(name);
    }
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Hello extends World {

    public Hello(String name) {
          super(name);
    }
}
```

When I instantiate an object using `context.getBean(Hello.class, "foo")`, I get back a Hello class bean. But when I `hello.print()`, it printed `null`.

Removing the final modifier resolved the issue. Whats going on here? Is spring having any limitations with final methods?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `@Component` and `@Scope` annotations from your abstract class?

Comment: nope @NicoVanBelle doesnt work

Comment: What is the value getting passed Hello constructor?

Comment: "foo" @KrishnaKuntala

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My assumption is that you use **CGLIB proxying**. You can check that by

```
context.getBean(Hello.class, "foo").getClass()
```

In that case Spring asks CGLIB to create a subclass of the Hello. That subclass gets the real instance of Hello class. This allows to override all the methods and then eventually call the target, here is how it looks approximately:

```
class Proxy extends Hello {
  Hello target;

  void print() {
     target.print();
  }
}
```

Because you marked your method as `final` Java doesn't allow overriding. And proxy itself (while is a subclass of Hello) doesn't get the `name` field initialized - it's null.

So your real `Hello#print()` method is not invoked - only `Proxy#print()` is called and `Proxy#name` is null, which results in null showing up in console.

Comment: Can you please add more details on how its happening? Proxy#print() inturn calls target.print() and target is indeed holding "foo" initialized by context.getBean(Hello.class, "foo")

Answer (score 0):

So workaround I came up to is to simply move method implementation that relies on autowiring to private method which won't be proxied by CGLIB.
That would result in a given example to:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public abstract class World {
    String name;

    public World(String name) {
          this.name = name;
    }

    final void print() {
          doPrint();
    }

    private void doPrint() {
          //name is populated here
          System.out.println(name);
    }
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Hello extends World {

    public Hello(String name) {
          super(name);
    }
}
```