# Transactional public method marked as final inside abstract class does not work in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

So, working with Spring and transactional management I noticied something weird today,

```
public abstract class Processer<T> {
    final Class<T> received;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    protected abstract void handle(T request);

    // transactional on final abstract method, here is the issue, 
    // when I remove final it works, but I want final
    @Transactional
    final public void safeHandle(String... args) {
         T request = objectMapper.map(args[1);
         handle(request);
    }
}
```

One of my extended sub classes,

```
@Component("ack-processor")
public class AckProcessor extends Processor<AckModel> {

   // doing this to register the received <T> object in the abstract class
   public AckProcessor() {
      super(AckModel.class)
   }

   protected void handle(AckModel request) { // some transactional statements}
}
```

Now when I call from caller method

```
// below is mocked, but assume we have a genric class that picks up the bean by component name, and could inject this abstract properly
// usually something like more than 1 of this processor extensions is present in my scenario
Processor<T> processor = context.getBean(AckProcessor.class);
processor.handle(...);
// here we get update/delete cannot be performed - javax.persistence.TransactionalRequired exception
```

My question is, when I annotate the abstract class `final` method with Transactional, the transactional is not started, but weird thing, my autowired objectMapper and received object are both being set as null, though the component was picked based on component name wiring "ack-processor", then when I remove the final signature and left the `@Transactional` it seems to work, both the transactional is enabled, and the object mapper is being set properly, but I lose the final signature. Which I don't want, I am not sure the docs explain why final methods cannot be transactional.

The reason is, in my real production scenario, the abstract class is not only with one generic `<T>`, it has `<T,R>` and it does a bunch of process, which is boiler plate on these generics and based on certain criteria passed in the `args` it calls the sub classes abstract method like, say, there is bunch of abstract methods, `successHandle(), failuerHandle(), onHoldHandle()` etc, so I need to imply my abstarct class method as final, as I don't want other classes to implement this, I don't want anyone implementing to mess up this handle boiler plate logic.

Comment: It's because of [proxying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386068/spring-accessing-field-from-final-method-returning-null).

Comment: I am so confused by this. Which method is made "final", which one is "Transactional" etc.? Simple examples instead of a wall of text would be helpful.

Comment: @Smutje updated the Processor with where I am trying to put the Transactional, and also comment, is this clear now?

Comment: Yeah, look at @Kayaman's comment- Spring can't create a proxy (method override) of `final` methods because of Java. Usually you don't want to mix Java inheritance and dependency injection as DI prevents you from using all common inheritance functionality as you can see here.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks, I went through the explanation, getting the idea now

Comment: @Smutje were you sharing any other post or link, I would still like to explore more on this, but for now I understand and get the general idea of this, will close this question soon, Thanks